# Mi código completo no responde

Tags: r

Estimables, tengo mi código y ya nada me responde, lo lee y en vez de aparecer el > en la consola, aparece un +

Importe ciertas librerias:

```
library(fitdistrplus)
library(MASS)
library(survival)
library(tidyverse)
library(ggplot2)  
library(actuar) 
library(e1071) 
library(FAdist)
library(gld)
library(MonteCarlo)
library(snow)

archivos <- c("2014_1.csv",
              "2014_2.csv",
              "2014_3.csv",
              "2014_4.csv",
              "2015_1.csv",
              "2015_2.csv",
              "2015_3.csv",
              "2015_4.csv",
              "2016_1.csv",
              "2016_2.csv",
              "2016_3.csv",
              "2016_4.csv",
              "2017_1.csv",
              "2017_2.csv",
              "2017_3.csv",
              "2017_4.csv",
              "2018_1.csv",
              "2018_2.csv",
              "2018_3.csv",
              "2018_4.csv",
              "2019_1.csv")

lista_df <- lapply(archivos, function (x) read.table(x, sep=";",header=T))
df_unido <- reduce(rbind, lista_df)
```

Dividí mi base de datos en las columnas que necesitaba:

```
df_unido_n <- df_unido %>% 
    dplyr::select(NombreCentral,POTENCIA_BRUTA_MWH,CONCENTRACION_PORCENTAJE_CO2) %>%
    filter(POTENCIA_BRUTA_MWH >0,!is.na(POTENCIA_BRUTA_MWH) , CONCENTRACION_PORCENTAJE_CO2 >0, !is.na(CONCENTRACION_PORCENTAJE_CO2))


nombres= df_unido_n$NombreCentral
nombres.factor=factor(nombres)
nmb=levels(nombres.factor)


lista_total= list()
for (i in 1:44){
    dfn=df_unido_n %>%
        filter(NombreCentral == nmb[i])
    lista_total[[i]]<-dfn
}
```

Gráficos ggplot

```
ggplot(lista_total[[24]], aes(x = CONCENTRACION_PORCENTAJE_CO2)) + geom_density()
ggplot(lista_total[[24]], aes(lista_total[[24]]$CONCENTRACION_PORCENTAJE_CO2)) + geom_histogram(binwidth = 1.2)
ggplot(lista_total[[24]], aes(lista_total[[24]]$CONCENTRACION_PORCENTAJE_CO2)) + stat_ecdf(geom = "point", size=1) + ggtitle("CDF GRAPHIC")
ggplot(lista_total[[24]], aes(x = CONCENTRACION_PORCENTAJE_CO2)) + geom_histogram(aes(y=..density..), binwidth=1, colour="black", fill="white") + geom_density(alpha=0.2, size=0.4) + ggtitle("DENSITY AND HISTOGRAM GRAPHIC")
quan <- quantile(lista_total[[24]]$CONCENTRACION_PORCENTAJE_CO2, probs = c(0.25, 0.5, 0.75, 1))

col_prueba=lista_total[[24]]$CONCENTRACION_PORCENTAJE_CO2
str(col_prueba)
summary(col_prueba)
plotdist(col_prueba, histo=TRUE, demp=TRUE)
descdist(col_prueba)
fw2_p <- fitdist(col_prueba, "weibull")
fw3_p <- fitdist(col_prueba, "weibull3", start = list(shape = 1, scale = 1)) 
fg_p <- fitdist(col_prueba, "gamma")
fln_p <- fitdist(col_prueba, "lnorm")
fex_p <- fitdist(col_prueba, "exp")
fgm_p <- fitdist(col_prueba, "gumbel", start=list(scale=50, location=50))
fn_p <- fitdist(col_prueba, "norm")
fll_p <- fitdist(col_prueba, "llogis", start = list(shape = 1, scale = 1))
fl_p <- fitdist(col_prueba, "logis")
fitGLD <- fit.fkml(col_prueba, method = "ML")
optGLD <- fitGLD$optim.results$par
opt <- round(optGLD ,1)
fgl_p<- fitdist(col_prueba, "gl", start=list(lambda1 = opt[1], lambda2 = opt[2], lambda3 = opt[3], lambda4 = opt[4]), method="mle", control=list(trace=0, REPORT=1))
```

Acá nuevamente ocupo ggplot, pero antes también tuve ciertos problemas acá, estos empezaron a fallar y no me gráficaba nada:

```
par(mfrow=c(2,2))
plot.legend<-c("Weibull","Weibull3","lnorm","gamma","exp","gumbel","norm","llogis","logis","g-lambda")
denscomp(list(fw2_p,fw3_p,fg_p,fln_p,fex_p,fgm_p,fn_p,fll_p,fl_p,fgl_p), plotstyle = "ggplot",legendtext = c("weibull-2P", "weibull-3P", "gamma", "lognormal", "exponential", "gumbel", "normal", "loglogistic", "logistic","g-lambda"))
cdfcomp(list(fw2_p,fw3_p,fg_p,fln_p,fex_p,fgm_p,fn_p,fll_p,fl_p,fgl_p), plotstyle = "ggplot",legendtext = c("weibull-2P", "weibull-3P", "gamma", "lognormal", "exponential", "gumbel", "normal", "loglogistic", "logistic","g-lambda"))
qqcomp(list(fw2_p,fw3_p,fg_p,fln_p,fex_p,fgm_p,fn_p,fll_p,fl_p,fgl_p), plotstyle = "ggplot",legendtext = c("weibull-2P", "weibull-3P", "gamma", "lognormal", "exponential", "gumbel", "normal", "loglogistic", "logistic","g-lambda"))
ppcomp(list(fw2_p,fw3_p,fg_p,fln_p,fex_p,fgm_p,fn_p,fll_p,fl_p,fgl_p), plotstyle = "ggplot",legendtext = c("weibull-2P", "weibull-3P", "gamma", "lognormal", "exponential", "gumbel", "normal", "loglogistic", "logistic","g-lambda"))

bootdist(fw2_p)
bootdist(fw3_p)
bootdist(fg_p)
bootdist(fln_p)
bootdist(fex_p)
bootdist(fgm_p)
bootdist(fn_p)
bootdist(fll_p)
bootdist(fl_p)
bootdist(fgl_p)
```

Antes solo tenía problema con el ggplot, pero ahora nada responde
Considerando que aparte quiero aplicar Montecarlo, y ya ocupe Bootstrapping y cada vez el código se volvía más lento, por favor ayuda!!!

Comment: Si te queda un `+` en la consola es porque el código está incompleto y R se queda esperando lo que falta. Casi seguro que está faltando algún paréntesis de cierre en alguna de las líneas. Te sugiero purgar el entorno e ir evaluando línea por línea para diagnosticar el problema. Alternativa o complementariamente si usas Rstudio a la izquierda en el editor de texto puede ser que salga un circulito rojo con una cruz blanca que indica un problema en la sintaxis en esa línea. Para eso el script debe estar guardado.

Comment: Nada, lo hago linea por linea y me sigue devolviendo lo mismo, y no me aparece ningún circulo rojo, y se que antes funcionaba, como que de a poco empezó a morir mi código

Comment: La idea de ejecutarlo línea por línea es identificar en qué línea falla y corregir el problema ahí, aparentemente agregando un `)` que falta. Más allá de eso, el código se ve algo complicado y haciendo muchas cosas a la vez.  Yo trato de separar cada proceso (los gráficos, las pruebas de hipótesis, las replicaciones) y se me hace más fácil modificarlo y mantenerlo. Un refactoring, digamos.

Comment: claro, lo intente, pero encontre una solución, que la verdad no sé que hace, pero recorde el comando alt+c, lo puse en mi código y anduvo, la verdad no sé que hizo eso, pero volvió a funcionar